# const is 'undefined' after setting new value to it from an async api call

Tags: reactjs

I have an application that calculates work shifts. One can add wishes for specific shifts, and they are automatically calculated. Backend works correctly and takes wishes into account, but when I call my api to get all wishes and try to print the output to web page, I get an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'EmpId' of undefined

Here is my simplified React app

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Wish from './components/wish'

const [shifts, setShifts] = useState('')
const [wishes, setWishes] = useState([])

  const addWish = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const wish = {
      EmpId: selectedEmployee,
      Shift: selectedShift,
      Day: selectedDay
    }
    await wishService.postWish(wish) //Posts the new wish. Works, and is taken into account by backend.
    setShifts(await shiftService.getAll()) //shiftService gets shifts as a string and works correctly, not necessary to implement here.
    setWishes(await wishService.getAll() //Gets all wishes from backend
    console.log(wishes) // Prints a correct-looking array of wishes. Example of wishes[0] 0: {id: 1, empId: 1, shift: 2, day: 3}
      }

//...

return (
<div>
  {wishes.map(wish =>
    <Wish key={wish.id} //Bang. Here wishes is all of a sudden undefined and error pops.
    EmpId={wish.EmpId}
    Day={wish.Day}
    WantedShift={wish.WantedShift}
</div>
```

Wish is a very simple module:

```
import React from 'react'

const Wish = ({ wish }) => {
   return (
     <div>
       {wish.EmpId} , {wish.Day} , {wish.WantedShift}
     </div>
   )
}

export default Wish
```

Here is also my WishService, which I think should work fine. At least both console.log calls make reasonable output.

```
import axios from 'axios'
const baseUrl = 'https://localhost:5001/api/ShiftWishes'

const getAll = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(baseUrl)
    const wishes = response.data
    console.log(wishes)
    return wishes
}

const postWish = async newObject => {
    const response = await axios.post(baseUrl, newObject)
    const wish = response.data
    console.log(wish)
    return wish
}

export default {getAll, postWish}
```

I have a feeling that the problem is something simple I just don't yet understand about async calls, but really cannot spot the problem since the calls seem to be working just fine, whole program worked fine until I wanted to print the wishes on screen. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is a scoping issue, hence why the calls being made in your async functions are being made correctly `await wishService.postWish(wish)` When you want to display wishes the code breaks since wishes is defined in the local scope of that async function and not globally.

Comment: just a stupid question to ask, but from the code provided you seem to have useState outside of a component flow, is this really the case?

Comment: No, in real life it is inside the app block, just forgot to add them to the sample edition :) will look at this again tomorrow with fresh eyes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the `Wish` Component , you are passing `EmpId, Day, WantedShift` props whereas the `Wish` component is expected a wish object containing these values

Change the below code,

```
return (
<div>
  {wishes.map(wish =>
    <Wish key={wish.id} //Bang. Here wishes is all of a sudden undefined and error pops.
    EmpId={wish.EmpId}
    Day={wish.Day}
    WantedShift={wish.WantedShift}
</div>)
```

Try doing the below:

```
return (
<div>
  {wishes.map(wish =>
    <Wish key={wish.id} wish={wish} />
</div>)
```

or change the `Wish` component

```
import React from 'react'

const Wish = ({ EmpId, Day, WantedShift }) => {
   return (
     <div>
       {EmpId} , {Day} , {WantedShift}
     </div>
   )
}

export default Wish
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has nothing to do with scope, it has to do with timing and the React lifecycle.  Calling any async functions *on render* is a huge no-no.  You should call those only from useEffect().  Also your render could should be aware that the variables will be null the first time the component is mounted.